# My school (follows/runs/runs on) a British curriculum?

Tags: grammar, verbs

While trying to describe the curriculum my school uses I found myself struggling to find the appropriate verb to use.  Do I say:

```
My school runs the CIE curriculum.
```

Or

```
My school follows the CIE curriculum.
```

Or

```
My school runs on the CIE curriculum.
```

So my question is what is the most appropriate verb to use in this context?

Thank you in advanced :)

Comment: You could say *"follows"* or *"uses"*.

Comment: I have seen *operates to a ... curriculum (and holiday timetable)*.

Comment: @PeterShor - you should make than an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say *"follows"* or *"uses"*. But *"run"* is a verb that isn't usually associated with *"curriculum"*.